# imageresizer How to write text onto image

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am using CropUp which is a component based on ImageResizer for Umbraco.

I would like to be able to write a short message on every image, placed in the bottom right hand corner.

I know there is a plugin (Watermark) that does this, but the website I am working on is for my local village can they cannot afford the $499 licence fee. So, I am looking to see if I can write my own.

They provide an example of how to start writing a plugin (http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/basics), but I am not sure how to "get hold of" the image and then "return it" once the text has been added!

I am using ImageResizer / CropUp (https://cropup.codeplex.com/) to create a cropped image of a source image - that is part of CropUp - I need to add text to the cropped image. There isn't a physical image on disk to work with.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961086/image-size-is-drastically-increasing-after-applying-a-simple-watermark

Comment: Look further down on that link to the gradient polygon example.

Comment: I saw the gradient example but it seems to be creating a new image, not altering (writing on) the "current" one?

Answer (score 1):

The ImageResizing functionality is great, but the [ImageGen project](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/imagegen) can generate a text based image, and an overlay.

Combining both should solve your problem by combining the URL of the text based image as a watermark, and the URL for the generated image:

```
http://localhost/umbraco/ImageGen.ashx?image=/media/watch.jpg&width=200
&text=DJR&fontsize=10&fontcolor=gray&align=right&valign=bottom
```

The link above is taken from the [ImageGen documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=9326). The basic functionality is free, but the overlay functionality requires a Pro License and costs 199 USD.

Comment: I have used ImageGen before and for this very reason (adding text to an image), but it doesn't have the user configurable cropping which is something I need. I did think about passing the CropUp / ImageResizer image through ImageGen as well, but that doesn't sound like the ideal solution!

Comment: That could be a solution if not too many changes are to be expected. If you have caching on both solutions, it might be possible. Though I wouldn't expect it to hold on high traffic sites.